# Using Ruby's ri tool can I get a list of classes that inherit the same method(s)?

Tags: ruby

Using Ruby's ri tool can I get a list of classes that implement the same method(s)? For example
Let's say that I wanted to know what classes implement `freeze` how would I find that out us ri?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the obvious ?

```
ri freeze
```

It should give you the list of everything implementing the `freeze` method.